# Powershell how to get the ParentProcessID by the ProcessID

Tags: powershell

I've problems to get the ParentProcessID from a Process where I have the ProcessID. I tried it like this, this is how it works with the ProcessID:

```
$p = Get-Process firefox
$p.Id
```

But if I try it with the ParentProcessID, it doesn't work:

```
$p.ParentProcessId
```

Is there a way to get the ParentProcessID by the ProcessID?

Comment: Yes, but not with Get-Process. You need to use CIM/WMI (Win32_Process)

Comment: gwmi win32_process something like this?

Comment: Yes, something like that. `Get-CimInstance Win32_Process -Filter "Name = 'firefox.exe'"|select ParentProcessId`

Comment: Yes it works, but I want to select it by the ProcessID I found the solution I'll post it as an anwser, thank you for your help.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
$p = Get-Process firefox
$parent = (gwmi win32_process | ? processid -eq  $p.Id).parentprocessid
$parent
```

The output is the following:

```
1596
```

And `1596` is the matching ParentProcessID I've checked it with the ProcessExplorer.

Comment: The equivalent for Powershell Core is `(Get-CimInstance CIM_Process | ? processid -eq $p.id).parentProcessId` (as Get-WmiObject is deprecated since PowerShell 3 according to https://stackoverflow.com/a/54508009/727345).

Answer (score 20):

As mentioned in the comments, the objects returned from `Get-Process` (`System.Diagnostics.Process`) doesn't contain the parent process ID.

To get that, you'll need to retrieve an instance of the Win32_Process class:

```
PS C:\> $ParentProcessIds = Get-CimInstance -Class Win32_Process -Filter "Name = 'firefox.exe'"
PS C:\> $ParentProcessIds[0].ParentProcessId
3816
```

Answer (score 14):

In PowerShell Core, the `Process` object returned by `Get-Process` cmdlet contains a Parent property which gives you the corresponding `Process` object for the parent process.

Example:

```
> $p = Get-Process firefox
> $p.Parent.Id
```

Comment: Note that this requires (elevated) administrator privileges. Otherwise it silently fails and the `Parent` member will be `$null`. The [WMI solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33912191/7571258) works with less privileges.

Comment: @zett42 I don't think this is true anymore, it's working for me on a PowerShell without administrative privileges.

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to get the PPID of the current running PS process, rather than for another process looked up by name.  The following worked for me going back to PS v2.  (I didn't test v1...)

```
$PPID = (gwmi win32_process -Filter "processid='$PID'").ParentProcessId
Write-Host "PID: $PID"
Write-Host "PPID: $PPID"
```