# How do I get the parent id of a process on powershell?

Tags: powershell, shell

```
clear
$name = Read-host -Prompt 'Name of service'
$p = Get-process $name

$id = $p.Id
$parentId = $p.Parent.Id
echo $parentId
```

I've tried this, but it doesn't return anything

Comment: [ParentProcessID](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33912278/10106356) - you can refer this already answered post.

Comment: @KarthickGanesan I've already tried it, but no matter what process I introduce, it always gives me the same number

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Powershell how to get the ParentProcessID by the ProcessID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33911332/powershell-how-to-get-the-parentprocessid-by-the-processid)

Comment: @Jorge - That logically translates to the child processes being triggered by the same Parent process. If you think it is not true, please share more details or sample output. You can also use 'Process Explorer' to validate your results.

Answer (score 0):

Get-Process doesn't contain parent ID, so you need to use Get-CimInstance

```
clear
$name = Read-host -Prompt 'Name of service'

$ParentProcessIds = Get-CimInstance -Class Win32_Process -Filter "Name = '$name'"
$output = $ParentProcessIds[0].ParentProcessId

Write-Host $output
```

[Powershell how to get the ParentProcessID by the ProcessID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33911332/powershell-how-to-get-the-parentprocessid-by-the-processid)

Comment: Doesn't work for me: `It cannot be indexed in a null matrix.`

Comment: That's the error you get when your $name doesn't contain a valid process name.
Try only run the two lines:

`$ParentProcessIds = Get-CimInstance -Class Win32_Process -Filter "Name = 'PROCESSNAME'"
$ParentProcessIds[0].ParentProcessId`

And hard-code the process name to make sure that it can find it.
For example start CMD and write "conhost.exe" as the process